# Including an array with a serialize form - jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, serialization

I currently have a form that I am trying to perform a post on (serializing the form), however I also want to include several checkboxes (but I don't want to include them in the form itself)

I have tried using jQuery's .post, but was unable to accomplish what I needed, any help would be greatly appreciated.

(I am using asp.net MVC 2.0 - and I figured this event would be attached to a button click)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish this, I'll demonstrate two for you, along with an example of a Controller Action to accept the data:

**Your Controller Action:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult YourActionName(YourModel formModel, bool[] checkboxes)
{
   ...
}
```

**[.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) Method:**

```
//Serialize Form Data
var data = $("#yourForm").serializeArray();

//Iterates through all your checkboxes - with a specific class
$(".yourCheckboxClass").each(function ()
{
    data.push({name : "checkboxes", value : $(this).val()});
});
```

**[.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) Method:**

```
//Build array of checkbox values
//You can use an .each here, or whatever other method you prefer

$.ajax({ type: "POST",
          url: "<%= Url.Action("Action","Controller") %>",
     datatype: "json",
  traditional: true,
         data: {
                  'formModel': $('#yourForm').serialize(),
                 'checkboxes': yourCheckboxArray
               }
});
```

I hope this helps you accomplish what you need.

Comment: I'm assuming that you will be processing them separately, otherwise you could accomplish the same by including the array in your Model.

Comment: Yes Rionmonster - Thank you for the quick reply. I just was unable to ever get the array to work properly on my own. I was trying something similar to your ajax method, but a little different.

Comment: One of the tricky parts with that is often you need to have the traditional : true section when using arrays. At least in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work for you? (assuming the button is the submit button on the form)

```
$("#triggerButton").bind("click.me", function(e) {
   var $form = $(this).closest("form");
   $(".other-checkbox-class").appendTo($form);
});
```